# Asp.net upload file using XMLHttpRequest c# server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I have the following client side function:

```
function UploadFile() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    formData.append("file", file);
    var uploadServerSideScriptPath = "Login.aspx/Img_Upload";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", uploadServerSideScriptPath, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Size", file.size);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Type", file.type);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

the server-side is:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void Img_Upload()
{
    HttpContext postedContext = HttpContext.Current;
    HttpPostedFile file = postedContext.Request.Files[0];

    string name = file.FileName;
    byte[] binaryWriteArray = new
    byte[file.InputStream.Length];
    file.InputStream.Read(binaryWriteArray, 0,
    (int)file.InputStream.Length);

    FileInfo file_Info = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
    string ext = file_Info.Extension;


    string file_Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Year + ext;

    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("img//profilePIC//" + file_Name), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    objfilestream.Write(binaryWriteArray, 0,
    binaryWriteArray.Length);
    objfilestream.Close();

}
```

I put a break-point inside Img_Upload but it never hits.
I used fiddler and the request seems ok.
any ideas why?

If I use var uploadServerSideScriptPath = "Login.aspx", I get to the page_load function.
The problem is to call a specific method on that page.

Comment: Your webmethod is not static. Change it like public static void Img_Upload()

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it doesn't work... :(

Comment: Your web method not called at all or you can't set the break point ?

Comment: I tried: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open("POST", "Login.aspx/test"); xhr.send(); to call [WebMethod]
    public static void test(object obj)
    {
        string a = "test";
    }doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

Try clientID for getElementByID() method as

```
...

    function UploadFile() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = document.getElementById("<%=file.ClientID%>").files[0];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating .axd handler and use ProcessRequest